# Python initial class variable keeps resetting after each call

Tags: python, class

I have a sample class below. self.number keeps resetting after each call of calculate function. I am expecting that when calculate function is called each time, self.number = self.number + 1, and each time I call self.number, I expect the accumulated value. I expect final result of 10 with 10 loops in the example below. Right now, the vaue self.number resets to 0 and add 1 each call.

```
class ExampleClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.number = 0

    def calculate(self):
        self.number = self.number + 1
        return self.number


for i in range(10):
    classID = ExampleClass()
    print(classID.calculate())
```

Comment: Think about how many `ExampleClass`es you're creating. Every instance of the class has its own `self.number`.

Comment: Remove the line `classID = ExampleClass()` from the loop, this is what is resetting your values by creating a new instance every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a new instance of the class inside the loop. So in each iteration of the loop a brand new `ExampleClass` object is being created & used.

To get your intended behavior, move the object instantiation outside the loop

```
classID = ExampleClass()
for i in range(10):
    print(classID.calculate())
```

Comment: I've never understood why newbies make this kind of mistake so often.

Comment: @Barmar Probably a misunderstanding of what instantiating objects really means and what classes are used for, and misunderstanding that the data is associated with instances, not the class itself (at least in cases like this). Or at least that's what I've gotten from talking to people with similar questions.

Comment: The "kind" of mistake I meant is more general -- initializing an accumulator variable inside the loop instead of before it. Like if they're concatenating strings, they put `s = ""` inside the loop.

Comment: @Barmar in what way are your comments helpful?

Comment: @HelloWorld123 Maybe if I understood better how new programmers think I could help them better. I have asked many of them what led them to write things like this, they think I'm insulting them.

Answer (score 0):

Because for every time you call `ExampleClass()` in the for loop `self.number` is initialized to 0.

to do what you expect you should try:

```
class ExampleClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.number = 0

    def calculate(self):
        self.number = self.number + 1
        return self.number

classID = ExampleClass()
for i in range(10):
    print(classID.calculate())
```